# Как перезагрузить класс по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: java, android, activity, button, math

Приветствую! На данный момент я имею 3 Activity посредством которых задаю и обрабатываю переменные для матрицы 3x3, при этом все эти Activity  подобны друг другу, отличаются лишь названиями задаваемых переменных, а в последствии и выводимыми переменными(т.е. на 1-ом задаются переменные: b, d; на 2-ом с,g; на 3-ем f,h).
При этом все арифметические операции я вывел в отдельный от всех Activity класс.
Именно в этот класс импортируются все заданные переменные, здесь происходят все арифметические операции. Считается всё верно.

Код MatrixMessageActivity123:

```
import static app.analysis.mai.MessageActivity1.b;
import static app.analysis.mai.MessageActivity1.d;
import static app.analysis.mai.MessageActivity2.c;
import static app.analysis.mai.MessageActivity2.g;
import static app.analysis.mai.MessageActivity3.f;
import static app.analysis.mai.MessageActivity3.h;

class MatrixMessageActivity123 {
static double a = 1;
static double e = 1;
static double i = 1;

static double w11 = Math.pow(a * b * c, 1.0 / 3);
static double w12 = Math.pow(d * e * f, 1.0 / 3);
static double w13 = Math.pow(g * h * i, 1.0 / 3);

static double r11 = w11 + w12 + w13;

static double q11 = w11 / r11;
static double q12 = w12 / r11;
static double q13 = w13 / r11;

static double s11 = a + d + g;
static double s12 = b + e + h;
static double s13 = c + f + i;

static double p11 = s11 * q11;
static double p12 = s12 * q12;
static double p13 = s13 * q13;

static double Y01max = p11 + p12 + p13;

static double IS11 = (Y01max - 3) / (3 - 1);

static double OC11 = IS11 / 0.58;
}
```

Однако, на всех 3-ёх Activity мне необходимо обработать кнопку возвращения в начало решения, в случае, допустим, пользовательской ошибки, т.е., например, было случайно задано не то значение переменной и т.д.

код кнопки:

```
return3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return3);
return3.setText("На этап оформления структуры");
return3.setOnClickListener(this);
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent13 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent13);
    finish();
}
```

Кнопка возвращает в начало решения, но тот самый класс (MatrixMessageActivity123), в котором вычисляется вся математика не сбрасывается, и никак не изменяет свои значения, если поверх ранее заданных значений, например, определить другие значений переменных. В любом случае обрабатывается только самый первый заданный вариант значений переменных матрицы. Другими словами, если, например, сначала задать заведомо неправильные значения, а потом вернуться в начало и задать правильные, то приложение выдаст, что опять введены неправильные значения, как и в первом случае.
Проверка осуществляется в рамках следующей конструкции, на 3-ем Activity:

```
if (OC11 < 0.1) {
toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов согласована, можете продолжить решение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.show();
                    sootnesen3.setEnabled(true);
                }
else if (OC11 >= 0.1) {
toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов несогласованна, задайте приоритеты заново", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.show();
                }
```

Вопрос: Возможно  ли  перезапустить класс MatrixMessageActivity123 по нажатию кнопки return3, для сброса ранее заданных значений переменных, или может есть иные пути решения данной проблемы? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Код MessageActivity1:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MessageActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView celzadach1, poyas4, poyas5, poyas6, text9, text10, text11;
RadioGroup rgroup1;
RadioButton sravnenkr1, sravnenkr2, sravnenkr3;
ListView spisok1;
Spinner spn2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
String prioritet1[] = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
String znachn1 = "";
Button sootnesen1, return1;
static double d, b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message1);

    Intent intent5 = getIntent();

    celzadach1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach1);
    String message1 = intent5.getStringExtra("message1");
    celzadach1.setText(message1);

    poyas4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas4);
    poyas4.setText("Определение важности критериев сравнения относительно заявленной цели:");

    poyas5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas5);
    poyas5.setText("Какой из сравниваемых критериев более предпочтительный?");

    poyas6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas6);
    poyas6.setText("Предпочтительней на сколько?");

    sravnenkr1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr1);
    String message2 = intent5.getStringExtra("message2");
    sravnenkr1.setText(message2);

    sravnenkr2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr2);
    String message3 = intent5.getStringExtra("message3");
    sravnenkr2.setText(message3);

    sravnenkr3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr3);
    sravnenkr3.setText("Сравниваемые критерии одинаково важны");

    sootnesen1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sootnesen1);
    sootnesen1.setText("Далее");

    return1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return1);
    return1.setText("На этап оформления структуры");
    return1.setOnClickListener(this);

    text9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text9);
    String message4 = intent5.getStringExtra("message4");
    text9.setText(message4);

    text10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text10);
    String message5 = intent5.getStringExtra("message5");
    text10.setText(message5);

    text11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text11);
    String message6 = intent5.getStringExtra("message6");
    text11.setText(message6);

    spisok1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spisokPrioritet1);
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prioritet1);
    spisok1.setAdapter(adapter2);

    rgroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
    rgroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes final int q1) {
            spisok1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long id) {
                    znachn1 = String.valueOf((adapter2.getItemId(0) < 9) ? 9 - id : 0);
                    if (q1 == sravnenkr1.getId()) {
                        b = Double.valueOf(znachn1);
                        d = 1 / b;
                    }
                    else if (q1 == sravnenkr2.getId()) {
                        d = Double.valueOf(znachn1);
                        b = 1 / d;
                    }
                }
            });

            if (q1 == sravnenkr3.getId()) {
                znachn1 = String.valueOf(1);
                d = Double.valueOf(znachn1);
                b = Double.valueOf(znachn1);
            }

            sootnesen1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent6 = new Intent(MessageActivity1.this, MessageActivity2.class);
                    intent6.putExtra("message1", celzadach1.getText().toString());
                    intent6.putExtra("message2", sravnenkr1.getText().toString());
                    intent6.putExtra("message3", sravnenkr2.getText().toString());
                    intent6.putExtra("message4", text9.getText().toString());
                    intent6.putExtra("message5", text10.getText().toString());
                    intent6.putExtra("message6", text11.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent6);
                    finish();
                }
            });



        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent11 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent11);
}
}
```

Код MessageActivity2:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MessageActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView celzadach2, poyas7, poyas8, poyas9, text12, text13, text14;
RadioGroup rgroup2;
RadioButton sravnenkr4, sravnenkr5, sravnenkr6;
ListView spisok2;
Spinner spn2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3;
String prioritet2[] = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
String znachn2 = "";
Button sootnesen2, return2;
static double c,g;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message2);

    Intent intent7 = getIntent();

    celzadach2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach2);
    String message1 = intent7.getStringExtra("message1");
    celzadach2.setText(message1);

    poyas7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas7);
    poyas7.setText("Определение важности критериев сравнения относительно заявленной цели:");

    poyas8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas8);
    poyas8.setText("Какой из сравниваемых критериев более предпочтительный?");

    poyas9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas9);
    poyas9.setText("Предпочтительней на сколько?");

    sravnenkr4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr4);
    String message2 = intent7.getStringExtra("message2");
    sravnenkr4.setText(message2);

    sravnenkr5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr5);
    String message4 = intent7.getStringExtra("message4");
    sravnenkr5.setText(message4);

    sravnenkr6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr6);
    sravnenkr6.setText("Сравниваемые критерии одинаково важны");

    sootnesen2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sootnesen2);
    sootnesen2.setText("Далее");

    return2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return2);
    return2.setText("На этап оформления структуры");
    return2.setOnClickListener(this);

    text12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text12);
    String message3 = intent7.getStringExtra("message3");
    text12.setText(message3);

    text13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text13);
    String message5 = intent7.getStringExtra("message5");
    text13.setText(message5);

    text14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text14);
    String message6 = intent7.getStringExtra("message6");
    text14.setText(message6);

    spisok2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spisokPrioritet2);
    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prioritet2);
    spisok2.setAdapter(adapter3);

    rgroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup2);
    rgroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes final int q2) {
            spisok2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position3, long id) {
                    znachn2 = String.valueOf((adapter3.getItemId(0) < 9) ? 9 - id : 0);
                    if (q2 == sravnenkr4.getId()) {
                        c = Double.valueOf(znachn2);
                        g = 1 / c;
                    }
                    else if (q2 == sravnenkr5.getId()) {
                        g = Double.valueOf(znachn2);
                        c = 1 / g;
                    }
                }
            });

            if (q2 == sravnenkr6.getId()) {
                znachn2 = String.valueOf(1);
                c = Double.valueOf(znachn2);
                g = Double.valueOf(znachn2);
            }

            sootnesen2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent8 = new Intent(MessageActivity2.this, MessageActivity3.class);
                    intent8.putExtra("message1", celzadach2.getText().toString());
                    intent8.putExtra("message2", sravnenkr4.getText().toString());
                    intent8.putExtra("message3", text12.getText().toString());
                    intent8.putExtra("message4", sravnenkr5.getText().toString());
                    intent8.putExtra("message5", text13.getText().toString());
                    intent8.putExtra("message6", text14.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent8);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent12 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent12);
}
}
```

Код MessageActivity3:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static app.analysis.mai.MatrixMessageActivity123.OC11;

public class MessageActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView celzadach3, poyas10, poyas11, poyas12, text15, text16, text17;
RadioGroup rgroup3;
RadioButton sravnenkr7, sravnenkr8, sravnenkr9;
ListView spisok3;
Spinner spn2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4;
String prioritet3[] = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
String znachn3 = "";
Button sootnesen3, return3;
Toast toast1;
static double f,h;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message3);

    Intent intent9 = getIntent();

    celzadach3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach3);
    String message1 = intent9.getStringExtra("message1");
    celzadach3.setText(message1);

    poyas10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas10);
    poyas10.setText("Определение важности критериев сравнения относительно заявленной цели:");

    poyas11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas11);
    poyas11.setText("Какой из сравниваемых критериев более предпочтительный?");

    poyas12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas12);
    poyas12.setText("Предпочтительней на сколько?");

    sravnenkr7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr7);
    String message3 = intent9.getStringExtra("message3");
    sravnenkr7.setText(message3);

    sravnenkr8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr8);
    String message4 = intent9.getStringExtra("message4");
    sravnenkr8.setText(message4);

    sravnenkr9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr9);
    sravnenkr9.setText("Сравниваемые критерии одинаково важны");

    sootnesen3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sootnesen3);
    sootnesen3.setText("Далее");
    sootnesen3.setEnabled(false);

    return3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return3);
    return3.setText("На этап оформления структуры");
    return3.setOnClickListener(this);

    text15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text15);
    String message2 = intent9.getStringExtra("message2");
    text15.setText(message2);

    text16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text16);
    String message5 = intent9.getStringExtra("message5");
    text16.setText(message5);

    text17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text17);
    String message6 = intent9.getStringExtra("message6");
    text17.setText(message6);

    spisok3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spisokPrioritet3);
    adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prioritet3);
    spisok3.setAdapter(adapter4);

    rgroup3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup3);
    rgroup3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes final int q3) {
            spisok3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position4, long id) {
                    znachn3 = String.valueOf((adapter4.getItemId(0) < 9) ? 9 - id : 0);

                    if (q3 == sravnenkr7.getId()) {
                        f = Double.valueOf(znachn3);
                        h = 1 / f;
                    }
                    else if (q3 == sravnenkr8.getId()) {
                        h = Double.valueOf(znachn3);
                        f = 1 / h;
                    }

                    if (OC11 < 0.1) {
                        toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов согласована, можете продолжить решение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast1.show();
                        sootnesen3.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else if (OC11 >= 0.1) {
                        toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов несогласована, задайте приоритеты заново", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast1.show();
                    }
                }
            });

            if (q3 == sravnenkr9.getId()) {
                znachn3 = String.valueOf(1);
                f = Double.valueOf(znachn3);
                h = Double.valueOf(znachn3);

                if (OC11 < 0.1) {
                    toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов согласована, можете продолжить решение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.show();
                    sootnesen3.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if (OC11 >= 0.1) {
                    toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов несогласована, задайте приоритеты заново", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.show();
                }
            }

            sootnesen3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent10 = new Intent(MessageActivity3.this, MessageActivity4.class);
                    intent10.putExtra("message1", celzadach3.getText().toString());
                    intent10.putExtra("message2", text15.getText().toString());
                    intent10.putExtra("message3", sravnenkr7.getText().toString());
                    intent10.putExtra("message4", sravnenkr8.getText().toString());
                    intent10.putExtra("message5", text16.getText().toString());
                    intent10.putExtra("message6", text17.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent10);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent13 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent13);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Очень кривая архитектура и сам код) Но на крайняк для достижения цели любыми путями сойдет. Как я понял , при неверных данных вы возвращаете пользователя на повторный ввод . И после того как он повторно введет , хотите чтобы MatrixMessageActivity123  воспроизвелся заново, т.е. произвел новый расчет ?

Comment: Покажите код где вы создаете экземпляр MatrixMessageActivity123 . Место , где,  после заполнения данных на последнем активити, вызывается класс для расчета

Comment: А еще лучше, если дополните  свой вопрос кодом всех классов. В данном случае будет проще дать ответ, чем читать ваши объяснения.

Comment: На данном языке пишу первый раз, код какой есть..
Да, я хочу, при любых ошибках, возвращать пользователя на повторный ввод, по нажатию на return1, return2 и return3, сопровождающимся сбросом значений переменных. MatrixMessageActivity123, как я понял, начинает свою работу с запуска приложения, и считает значения ОС11 по мере определения значений b,d,c,g,f и h матрицы. Извиняюсь за такую дилетантность, мои познания в java несколько слабы..

Comment: хм. Видите в 3 активити, в onClick , есть переход на некую 4 активити. MessageActivity4.class . А где код этого активити?

Comment: это уже следующий активити, на ней будет обрабатываться другая матрица 2х2, с другими переменными не относящихся к данной матрице..

Comment: и кода к ней пока нет (MessageActivity4.class)..  с этой надо закончить

Comment: Очень тяжко с таким кодом разобраться, даже названия переменных кривые. Предлагаю скинуть весь код проекта мне на почту, я в android studio очень быстро пойму что к чему. Или же если можете выложите код на гитхаб. Можете на яндекс диск выложить . в общем как удобно. Нужен проект целиком. почта turalllb@mail.com

Comment: такого адреса почты не существует, у меня так

Comment: странно, тогда сюда. turalllb1991@gmail.com

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/xARtci6N3RqqpE
ссылка на Яндексдиск

Comment: я так понимаю, ответ показывается в этой строчке  text18.setText("OC11="+OC11);

Comment: вижу, что ничего из нашей прошлой беседы вам освоить не удалось. невозможно понять, что происходит в вашем коде

Comment: Sir.., Я кажется понял в чем ваша проблема. Вот смотрите. Вы на пришли на  MessageActivity2 , у вас выполнился метод onCreate(). Ведь именно в этом методе у вас рассчитываются значения. И вот пользователь ошибся. Вы уходите назад на Activity1, оформить иерархию. Переоформили. И теперь снова по порядку , сперва  MessageActivity1 . Вы хотите чтобы в нем выполнился onCreate() и рассчитал все заново, но этого не будет. Метод onCreate() выполняется только при первом создании активити. Выход у вас один. Когда вы возвращаетесь к своей иерархии, вам надо уничтожить прошлые активити.

Comment: pavlofff, да это очень страшный код, какое же это упорство надо иметь, чтобы продолжать в нем копаться))

Comment: Несколько раз пробежавшись по коду, так и не понял, где "динамика" в MatrixMessageActivity123 - где вы ожидаете получить обновленный MatrixMessageActivity123, но не получаете?

Comment: У него в активити4, выводится в textView  переменная OC11 из класса , с кучей статических переменных. Это я как понимаю и есть решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent11 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent11);
    finish();
}
```

В каждом вашем методе, который возвращает к переоформлению иерархии добавьте строчку finish();

И в этом

```
` @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent12 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent12);
        finish();
    }`
```

И в этом

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent13 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent13);
        finish();
    }
```

**UPD** 
 Кроме того, что добавили выше, приведем класс к такому виду:

```
public class MessageActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView  text18, text19, text20;
    MatrixMessageActivity123 matrixMessageActivity123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message4);
        matrixMessageActivity123 = new MatrixMessageActivity123();
        matrixMessageActivity123.Solve();

        text18 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text18);
        text18.setText("OC11=" + OC11);
    }
}
```

и :

```
 class MatrixMessageActivity123 {
    static double a = 1;
    static double e = 1;
    static double i = 1;

    static double w11 = Math.pow(a * b * c, 1.0 / 3);
    static double w12 = Math.pow(d * e * f, 1.0 / 3);
    static double w13 = Math.pow(g * h * i, 1.0 / 3);

    static double r11 = w11 + w12 + w13;

    static double q11 = w11 / r11;
    static double q12 = w12 / r11;
    static double q13 = w13 / r11;

    static double s11 = a + d + g;
    static double s12 = b + e + h;
    static double s13 = c + f + i;

    static double p11 = s11 * q11;
    static double p12 = s12 * q12;
    static double p13 = s13 * q13;

    static double Y01max = p11 + p12 + p13;

    static double IS11 = (Y01max - 3) / (3 - 1);

    static double OC11 = IS11 / 0.58;

    public void Solve(){
        OC11 = IS11 / 0.58;
    }
}
```

**UDP2**  добавить повторное вычисление в

```
spisok3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position4, long id) {
                        znachn3 = String.valueOf((adapter4.getItemId(0) < 9) ? 9 - id : 0);

                        if (q3 == sravnenkr7.getId()) {
                            f = Double.valueOf(znachn3);
                            h = 1 / f;
                        }
                        else if (q3 == sravnenkr8.getId()) {
                            h = Double.valueOf(znachn3);
                            f = 1 / h;
                        }

                        matrixMessageActivity123.Solve();


                        if (OC11 < 0.1) {
                            toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов согласована, можете продолжить решение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast1.show();
                            sootnesen3.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        else if (OC11 >= 0.1) {
                            toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Матрица локальных приоритетов несогласована, задайте приоритеты заново", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast1.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72349/discussion-on-answer-by-turalllb-------).